# Hyperref ignores \setdefaultlanguage from polyglossia

Tags: xetex, hyperref, languages, polyglossia

I use `polyglossia` to set my default language with `\setdefaultlanguage` to German. This works for the captions of tables, figures etc.
I want to reference to these figures with the `\autoref` command of the `hyperref` package. But `hyperref` ignores the default language setting. But the reference name stays English (*Table*), although the caption title is showed German (*Tabelle*).

A minimal XeLaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}                                                                          
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Testtabelle}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
                bla     & blub \\
                blabla  & blubblub \\
        \end{tabular}
        \label{test}
\end{table}
Die Tabelle \autoref{test}.
\end{document}
```

I use a workaround
`\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tabelle}` to rename the reference. But of course, this is only a workaround and no real solution.

Has anybody any idea solving this issue?

Answer (score 6):

A workaround is to pass the language as package option to `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage[german]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Testtabelle}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
                bla     & blub \\
                blabla  & blubblub \\
        \end{tabular}
        \label{test}
\end{table}
Die Tabelle \autoref{test}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, too.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got:
`
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [brazil]
Adding the global options:
  ,brazil
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
`

I did as the help suggested, but won't it use babel instead of polyglossia?

Comment: @MateusFelipe: The answer is now 8 1/2 years old. The package might have changed during this time. Feel free to post a new question with an example document which shows your problem and link back to this thread.