# Make hyperref's \autoref output in Bulgarian

Tags: hyperref, languages

I'm trying to use `hyperref` for references, but by default it outputs them in English like "chapter 2". According to [Hyperref ignores \setdefaultlanguage from polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21255/hyperref-ignores-setdefaultlanguage-from-polyglossia), doing

```
\usepackage[bulgarian]{hyperref}
```

Should do the trick, but this gives me a cryptic error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `bulgarian' undefined in families `Hyp'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4319 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

Note that it works for `german`. Here is my styling:

```
\ProvidesPackage{style}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
% \newfontfamily{\TelSubstFont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Cantarell}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}
\setdefaultlanguage{bulgarian}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[bulgarian]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdflang=bg}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

P.S. I'm still new to LaTeX, using XeLaTeX to compile the document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Bulgarian is not yet supported, you can convince it to cooperate with `hyperref` by defining the needed keywords yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HyLang@bulgarian\else
\appto\blockextras@bulgarian{%
  \def\equationautorefname{Equation}%
  \def\footnoteautorefname{footnote}%
  \def\itemautorefname{item}%
  \def\figureautorefname{Figure}%
  \def\tableautorefname{Таблица}%
  \def\partautorefname{Part}%
  \def\appendixautorefname{Appendix}%
  \def\chapterautorefname{chapter}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{section}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{subsection}%
  \def\subsubsectionautorefname{subsubsection}%
  \def\paragraphautorefname{paragraph}%
  \def\subparagraphautorefname{subparagraph}%
  \def\FancyVerbLineautorefname{line}%
  \def\theoremautorefname{Theorem}%
  \def\pageautorefname{page}%
}
% \inlineextras@bulgarian is empty, so we simply set it
% equal to \blockextras@bulgarian
\let\inlineextras@bulgarian\blockextras@bulgarian
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}\label{A}
\end{table}
\autoref{A}

\end{document}
```

Here I have modified from the English keywords only the one corresponding to "Table". A picture of the result:

[image]

The `\ifdefined...\fi` wrapper means that when `hyperref` will have the support for Bulgarian, the part in between will not be read any more.

Answer (score 20):

The Bulgarian language is not yet supported in package `hyperref`, because I, as maintainer of `hyperref`, am not familiar with that language and nobody has sent me the Bulgarian names for the `\autoref` names. If someone can send me the Bulgarian translations, then I can add them to `hyperref`. The definitions of `\HyLang@english` and/or `\HyLang@russian` could be used as starting point for the translation. I prefer the LaTeX names for the Cyrillic glyphs
as in `\HyLang@russian`, because `hyperref` should work with many input encodings and TeX compilers. UTF-8 should also be fine, then I can try the conversion myself.

The `\autoref` names can also be redefined:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{New section name}
```

See the manual of `hyperref` that also contains an example with the `babel` language package.

### Bulgarian names

With the help of [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#en/bg/), the comparison of [lshort-english](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) with [lshort-bulgarian](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/lshort/bulgarian/lshort-bg.pdf), and gloss-bulgarian.ldf of [polyglossia](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) I managed the following table.
(The font setting is taken from egreg's file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
EN & BG/UTF-8 & source \\
\hline
Equation & уравнение \\
footnote & бележка под линия /  забележка под линия & / lshort \\
item & точка \\
Figure & Фигура / фигура & lshort\\
Table & Таблица / таблица & lshort \\
Part & част \\
Appendix & апендикс / Приложение & / polyglossia \\
chapter & глава & lshort \\
section & Раздел / раздел & lshort \\
subsection & подраздел\\
subsubsection & подраздел / подподраздел ? \\
paragraph & параграф \\
subparagraph & подпараграф ? \\
line & редица \\
Theorem & теорема \\
page & страница / стp.  & lshort\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, there is plenty room for corrections:

- Which names should have the first character as uppercase letter. What are the conventions in the Bulgarian language, if things like chapters, figures, pages, ...
  are referenced?
- Are the translations correct, which is the best variant?
- What about *sub*section, *sub**sub*section, and *sub*paragraph?

Comment: I would like to help and provide translations, the problem is that I'm not very good with TeX (I'm a developer, though). Contact me at: emil dot vladev at gmail if interested. I'll most likely succeed if you send me a template(s) in English, along with some explanations what to translate and I will send it back to you translated (in UTF8 of course, I didn't get the glyphs part, something LaTeX specific?).

Comment: Which names should have the first character as uppercase letter. What are the conventions in the Bulgarian language, if things like chapters, figures, pages, ... are referenced? - Unless it's the start of a new sentence, it's lowercase.

Are the translations correct, which is the best variant? - Yes, actually. Some are better, though - footnote is better as "бележка под линия", appendix as "приложение", subsubsection just doesn't sound well in Bulgarian, it's better to be the same as subsection ("подраздел"). Same for subparagraph.

Comment: Line, if it's in case of a line in a law, the word is "алинеа". "редица" is more like row. I would need an example in English for that. Page is ok to be shortened as "стр.". Subsection is ok and correct.

Comment: In catalan, the same happens (unexisting translation) although there is a [bug](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?265) with proposed translation