# Default language for both polyglossia and fixme

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia, fixme

Is it possible to change the default language for both the polyglossia and fixme package at the same time?

After v1.2.0 polyglossia no longer supports loading language definition files as package options and fixme is not aware of language set by `\setdefaultlanguage`.

Minimal XeLaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish} % set language for polyglossia

\usepackage[draft, danish]{fixme} % set language for fixme

\begin{document}

\listoffixmes
\tableofcontents

\section{My section}
Some text\fxnote{This needs fixing.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the [same problem with polyglossia and hyperref.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21255/hyperref-ignores-setdefaultlanguage-from-polyglossia)

Comment: Add `danish` to the class options; but you need to `\setmainlanguage` anyway.